# Will a reference-request tag be made available in the site?

Tags: feature-request, tags

In relation to the question I asked [here](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/why-does-python-ignore-type-hints) I was looking for a [reference-request](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag, similar to the one available in Matter Modelling Stack Exchange. I managed to get stellar answers with references even without the tag, but it would have been great to have such a tag, to explicitly indicate that references would be appreciated. The use case would be when someone asks for a specific design choice and is requesting references to back up the provided answers. So is there any chance such a tag would be made available?

Comment: What is wrong with simply asking "please provide references" in the question?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in writing like that. My thought was that such a tag would make it easier to sort those kind of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Private Beta.

This might sound crazy, but everyone, including you, has enough reputation to create tags:

[image]

The tags that we currently have, were made by users creating them based on their own judgement.

If a tag gets created and becomes a matter of dispute, users can propose edits which burninate the new tag, and these will enter the review queue. If users disagree with the result of that process, they can raise the matter here on Meta.

Your question mentions that you have been active on MMSE. I'll mention that on MMSE there's a [tags chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107328/tags) which is another place in which tag-related discussions can happen in addition to the site's Meta, but it's not clear yet that such a room is necessary here at PLDI.

Comment: Also: before creating a new tag for one's own question, it's a good idea to search for other questions that the tag should also be added to. If there *are* any, add the tag to them too; but if there *aren't* any, think twice about creating the new tag.

Comment: @RayButterworth I agree with both of those suggestions. I can edit them into my answer when I'm on a computer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure such a tag is necessary; it seems like a [meta tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283907/are-meta-tags-banned-across-the-board-on-all-stack-exchange-sites-or-can-each-si) to me ─ it describes what form you want an answer to take, not the topic of the question.

Meta tags can be allowed here if we choose to allow them, but I don't think the community has made a firm decision on that yet. We already have at least one meta tag [pros-cons](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pros-cons), and there's a discussion [here](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/89) about whether that tag should exist, with no consensus reached yet on whether meta tags are OK.

So I'd say that for now, it's fine to unilaterally create tags for topics or concepts, but probably best to hold off on creating meta tags until there's some sort of community agreement about them. It sounds at the moment that you're already getting references in answers without using this tag, so perhaps this one is not necessary. If you want to be explicit about encouraging answers to include references, I think it's fine to write that in the question.

I should add that [questions shouldn't *only* ask for references](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/261/89).